# Move mixture of versioned and unversioned files and folders

Tags: svn

I can move unversioned files via

```
mv * subfolder/
```

and versioned files via

```
svn mv * subfolder/
```

(apart from the problem that `subfolder` is in `*`)

But **how can I move files if half of them are versioned and the other half is not?**

Comment: Have you tried the latter? If so, what error(s) are you getting?

Comment: @alroc `svn: 'file.end' is not under version control` then svn stops and does not proceed with the other files

Answer (score 0):

I would do a `find . \! \( -name .svn -prune \)` and pipe that to a `while read` (make this simple, assuming no directories or files with tabs or `\n` characters in them). Then, do a `svn mv` on that file. If that fails, you know it's an unversioned file, and you can do a simple `mv` on it:

```
$ find . \! \( -name .svn -prune \) | while read file
do
    if ! svn mv $file $new_location
    then
        mv $file $new_location
    fi
done
```

The actual code is going to be trickier than this. What if the directory where you're moving the file exists? What if it doesn't exist? Is this a directory you're moving or a file? All of these will affect exactly how you'd move the file.

The real question is why do you suddenly find yourself doing this. Where did all of these unversioned files come from, and why must they too be moved to another directory in your workspace?

Comment: the unversioned files are files that I do not version because they are too big, are temporary, are copies of someone else's files etc. Sure there is always ways to arrange your files more perfectly such that this would not be necessary, but in practice I often find myself in situations that would not exist in a perfect world. Most important for me is that my important files are versioned so I do not lose anything

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
for f in svn ls .; do svn mv $f subfolder; done
mv * subfolder
```

You'd still have to handle `subfolder`. `.svn` doesn't match the `*`, however you might have to take care of files and directories whose name begins with a dot.